# how to animate launch image once app has finished launching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, launching-application

I was wondering how I can manipulate the launch image of an iPhone app? I have put launchImage.png into my plist file (under Launch image (iPhone)) and when the app starts I would like to animate this launch image out of the view, like so:

```
launchImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-CGRectGetWidth(launchImage.frame), 0);
```

But how do I access an image which I've defined in my plist?

Or will I simply load another instance of the image and then animate it out of the way? This appears a little cumbersome, especially as the app has already loaded the launch image.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to load another instance.  You can't access the launch image from your app.  I usually just make a UIImage that matches the launch image and in my viewDidAppear method I animate it away with a `performSelector:withDelay:` of a second or 2.

Comment: thanks. why the delay though? i guess i will just have to try this even though it's a little annoying that you can't manipulate the launch image... oh well.

Comment: The delay gives you some control over how long the image is up and keeps it from popping out too soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a UIImageView instance set to display your launch image, put it on the root view controller's view, then animate it out of the way as you've described (perhaps in `-viewDidAppear:`). As far as I know, there's no API mechanism for interacting with the launch image directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load up the launch image again and then animate it out.